# Printer is always "waiting for the printer to become available"

Tags: arch-linux, cups, printer, hp, hp-printer

My printer used to work very well with CUPS and the named driver. Since a while, it often shows the German equivalent of

> Waiting for the printer to become available

(original: "Warte darauf dass der Drucker verfügbar wird") whenever I try to print something, even though the printer should be available.

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- DE: Plasma 5.20.3
- Printer: HP  LaserJet P1102 [Devicehunt with Vendor ID](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/03F0/device/002A)
- Driver: Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2 (recommended)

The problem is well known and seems to be independent of the specific printer model, but the usual [solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/waiting-for-printer-to-become-available-4175652261/) does not work for me. I've added the rule with no effect.

```
$ lsusb                                                                                                    
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 03f0:002a HP, Inc LaserJet P1102

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usbprinter.rules
ATTR{idVendor}=="03F0", ATTR{idProduct}=="002A", MODE:="0660", GROUP:="lp", ENV{libsane_matched}:="yes"
```

I've also tried different USB ports and restarted CUPS (`sudo systemctl restart cups.service`), my desktop and my printer several times as well as reinstalling CUPS and `foo2zjs-z2` (from AUR). Whenever I clear the printing queue and try to print something, the waiting message appears quickly. Trying to print the test page is not different.

Weird side effect: The number of pages in the top entry in the printing queue gets incremented every time I restart cups (e.g. shows 5, despite the document only having 1 page, since I've restarted CUPS 4 times after queueing the job).

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Arch had an update that changed the file `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` by providing a file at that position called `cupsd.conf.pacnew`.

I replaced cupsd.conf with the "pacnew" file, restarted cups and my printers were running again...

Comment: There's no such `.pacnew` file for me, even after updating everythig.